Why must the set of zeros for f be finite
Corollary 1.10 (Weierstrass-Hurwicz Theorem)

Assume $f_n: U \to \mathbb{C}$ is a sequence of non-zero analytic
functions. If $f_n$ converges uniformly on compact sets to a continuous
function $f$ (i.e., if $K \subset U$ is compact, then $\sup_{z \in K} 
  |f(z) - f_n(z)| \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$), then:

$f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic.
$f$ either has no zeros or is identically zero.
For the first part (due to Weierstrass), one only needs to show that for >any simple closed curve $\gamma \subset U$, we have that
$$
\left| \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz \right| \leq \underbrace{\left| \int_{\gamma} f_n(z) \, dz \right|}_{= 0} + \left| \int_{\gamma} (f(z) - f_n(z)) \, dz \right|
$$
$$
\leq 0 + \text{length}(\gamma) \underbrace{\left( \sup_{z \in K} |f(z) - f_n(z)| \right)}_{\to 0}.
$$
where the first term is zero by Gousart's theorem (since $f_n:U\to\mathbb{C}$ is analytic).
Thus, $\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = 0$ for all simple closed curves, and so $f$ is analytic by Morera's Theorem.
For the second part (due to Hurwitz), if $f(z)$ isn't identically zero, then the set of zeros $\{z_i\}_{i=1}^N$ of $f(z)$ is finite. We need to show that this set is empty. Assume for a contradiction that it isn't empty, and let $\gamma$ be a closed simple curve that contains one of these zeros, say $z_1$. By the Argument Principle, we have
$$
0 = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f_n'(z)}{f_n(z)} \, dz \to \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz > 0
$$
as $n \to +\infty$, which gives a contradiction.


I am currently unsure on the first part of the proof of the second result. Why can we not have an infinite number of zeros for $f$?
I know that the number of zeros on any compact set must be finite, however on the set $U$ could we not construct a function that had infinitely many isolated zeros?
If i take $U = \mathbb{C} \setminus ({0})$ and $f(z) = \sin(\frac{1}{z})$
$f$ is analytic on $U$, and the zeroes are at $z = \frac{1}{n\pi}$. Since the limit point is outside of $U$, these points are all isolated and we have infinitely many of them.
What am I missing?

Is not easier to consider $U=\Bbb C$ and $f(z)=\sin(z)$ than your example?

Maybe be cause the function $f$ is the limit of $f_n$, which is only defined on a compact set $K \subset U$. I don't think they defined $f$ on the whole open set U.

@Tri The number $1$ specifically says: $f:U \to \Bbb C$, and "convergence uniformly on compact sets" is a very common hypothesis in complex variable. It means that for every compact set $K \subset U$ the convergence is uniform. There is never a fixed compact set $K$ here.

@jjagmath Oh I didn't see that, sorry for the stupid comment.

@jjagmath I suppose that example is simpler, it also has infinitely many isolated zeros. I thought of mine purely because I was working with that function for something else before and so it was the first thing that came to mind. I do not understand how these functions do not contradict the statement in the proof?

You are right in that there is a priori no reason for $f$ to only have finitely many zeros. If you look at the presented argument more carefully though, you might notice that this fact is never really used.
All you need is that the set of zeros of $f$ is discrete if $f\not\equiv 0$. Say $z_1\in U$ is such a zero of $f$. Then you can find $r>0$ such that $B:=\overline{B_r(z_1)}\subseteq U$ and $f(z)\neq 0$ for $z\in B\setminus\lbrace z_1\rbrace$.
Now you can follow the proposed reasoning with $\gamma=\partial B$ and arrive at the desired contradiction.
